# Android how to make an activity reusable

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity which is used to show images in my app. Now that activity is pretty expensive to initialize (takes about 1-2 seconds) and I was wondering if I could somehow make it initialize when I launch the app and just send it new intents every time instead of initializing it all over again.
I thought maybe the launch mode property could help but I don't know how to use it to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't get confuse with **launchMode** stuff. Simply introduce `AsyncTask` in your activity to perform heavy lifting. Doing so will enable your activity to load/show faster.

Moreover, if you are still interested to go for **launchMode**, then set `android:launchMode="singleTop"` and in your activity code handle `onNewIntent()` event. Make sure you are not destroying/finishing your activity, otherwise `onCreate()` will be called.

Comment: I should've probably mentioned this but most of the heavy lifting is done during layout (it's a fairly complex layout), so another thread is (I think) out of the question

Comment: then go for `android:launchMode="singleTop"`

Comment: How do I make sure the activity isn't destroyed when I say, hit the back button?

Comment: on back-key pressed, your activity will always be destroyed, unless you handle back-key event manually and do something else, like showing a warning or launch a new or existing activity

Comment: But if I tried to mimic the back action without destroying the activity by calling the previous activity, wouldn't that previous activity be created again?

Comment: no, because your previous activity will be in **onStop** state.

Comment: But it won't be on top of the stack, which will make Android create a new instance of it if I'm not mistaken

Comment: if your previous activity is marked as `android:launchMode="singleTop"` and then you launch it again, the framework will call its **onNewIntent** method rather than re-creating it from scratch

Comment: I think that will only happen if the activity is at the top of it's stack (says so in the docs) - which it is not, because my activity is at the top of the stack.